# Suppress "None" output as string in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

How do I persuade Jinja2 to not print `"None"` when the value is `None`?

I have a number of entries in a dictionary and I would like to output everything in a single loop instead of having special cases for different keywords.  If I have a value of `None` (the `NoneType` not the string) then the string `"None"` is inserted into the template rendering results.

Trying to suppress it using 
`{{ value or '' }}` works too well as it will replace the numeric value zero as well.

Do I need to filter the dictionary before passing it to Jinja2 for rendering?

Comment: Is there any way to do it without interfering with the template?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In new versions of Jinja2 (2.9+):

`{{ value if value }}`

In older versions of Jinja2 (prior to 2.9):

`{{ value if value is not none }}` works great.

if this raises an error about not having an else try using an else ..

`{{ value if value is not none else '' }}`

Comment: I got an error with this: `UndefinedError: the inline if-expression evaluated to false and no else section was defined.`

Comment: `{{ value if value != None else ''  }}` may be necessary to avoid the problem @GeenHenk had

Comment: I think `is not None` instead of `!= None` should be used.

Comment: Today this just gives me `TemplateAssertionError: no test named 'None'`

Comment: As of 2017 (Jinja 2.9), you just need `{{ value if value }}`. No need of comparing to None.

Answer (score 36):

Another option is to use the `finalize` hook on the environment:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> e = jinja2.Environment()
>>> e.from_string("{{ this }} / {{ that }}").render(this=0, that=None)
u'0 / None'
```

but:

```
>>> def my_finalize(thing):
...     return thing if thing is not None else ''
...
>>> e = jinja2.Environment(finalize=my_finalize)
>>> e.from_string("{{ this }} / {{ that }}").render(this=0, that=None)
u'0 / '
```

Comment: I think this is the smartest way to do it. However, when I tried this method with FastAPI's jinja2, `url_for()` in the template stopped working. For your information.

Answer (score 30):

[Default filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default):

```
{{ value|default("", True) }}
```

Comment: this has the same problem as OP's main solution... I think this would work as  {{ value|default("", **True** ) }}

Comment: Without the True, this doesn't work at all. With the True, it replaces the None and the numeric zero .. so no good.

Comment: You are right, it only works when the variable isn't defined instead of assigning None to it. But writing a filter for the None case would be worth it just for being less verbose than the chosen answer.

Comment: I like this solution the best.

Answer (score 23):

A custom filter can solve the problem. Declare it like this:

```
def filter_suppress_none(val):
    if not val is None:
        return val
    else:
        return ''
```

Install it like this:

```
templating_environment.filters['sn'] = filter_suppress_none
```

Use it like this:

```
{{value|sn}}
```

Comment: Possibly the most elegant solution here. Jinja could have a filter like this, maybe with less cryptic name than "sn" :)

Comment: Great answer.  One nitpick: `if val is not None` would be more readable.

Comment: Also love this answer, but minor correction: 'suppress' is spelled wrong in function def.

Answer (score 23):

According to this post from the Pocco Mailing List: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pocoo-libs/SQ9ubo_Kamw/TadIdab9eN8J

Armin Ronacher (creater of Jinja2/Flask, etc...) recommends the following "pythonic" snippet:

`{{ variable or 0 }}` `{{ variable or '' }}`

The notion here being that once again, explicit is preferable to implicit.

Edit: The selected answer is definitely the correct one. I haven't really come across a situation where a template variable would be either a string or the numeric zero, so the above snippets might help reduce the code noise in the template.

Comment: It was noted in the question that this does not help because it also suppresses numeric zero

Answer (score 0):

if you are using flask:

```
app.jinja_env.finalize = lambda x: x if x is not None else ''
```